# Bash Script: Alphabetize strings without using -sort

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I'm trying to alphabetize three strings and then concatenate them together.  So for example if I have:

```
a="zebra"
b="ape"
c="fox"
```

I should end up with apefoxzebra

I need to do with WITHOUT using sort.

Here's what Ive been trying to alphabetize the strings, but it doesn't seem to be sorting right.  It just picks 'a' every time.

```
a="zebra"
b="aardvark"
c="cat"


if [[ "$a" -le "$b" && "$a" -le "$c" ]]; then
    first=$a

elif [[ "$b" -le "$a" && "$b" -le "$c"  ]]; then
        first=$b
    else
         first=$c
fi
```

Comment: Should that second block be `first=$b` instead of `first=$a`?

Comment: You're right!  I copied it wrong.

Comment: `-le` is for arithmetic comparison. To compare strings lexicographically, use `<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @gniourf_gniourf for the answer!

> `-le` is for arithmetic comparison. To compare strings
>   lexicographically, use `<`.